# Install KVM on Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Core

Tags: ubuntu, server, kvm

I bought a Asus W680 motherboard with ECC RAM to use it as a NAS and also run some Ubuntu Servers on it. All installs (like NAS, additional servers, pfsense) should run in own Virtual Machines.
Therefore the idea would be to install KVM on a bare metall and then run the VM's in KVM.

What is the recommendations for such a setup. Ubuntu Server to install KVM or Ubuntu Core 20 to install KVM.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Server, I should think; it may take a little more space, but it will provide fewer chances for annoyances.